# Правильная связка DAL и BLL?

Tags: c#, mvc

Не поможете?

У меня здесь функция, которая находится в проекте BLL, и чтобы представление напрямую не обращалось к DAL, созданы промежуточные классы, один из которых CityDTO (а в DAL это City).

Также в DAL есть функция, которая по предикату возвращает коллекцию IEnumerable.

В BLL (конкретно в этой функции) я маппю City в CityDTO и этот CityDTO возвращаю представлению.

И вот такая проблема: когда я в PresentationLayer вызываю эту функцию c BLL и пытаюсь туда передать предикат, мне студия пишет, что нельзя так сделать, мол, нужно сначала добавить ссылку на DAL, но этого делать нельзя (из-за архитектуры).

И в параметре этой функции City тоже нельзя поменять на CityDTO, так как в DAL вызываемая функция принимает City и никак по-другому.

И вот что делать в такой ситуации? Может кто шарит?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо, разобрался

Comment: Можете написать в поле ответ свой вариант решения, это не запрещено правилами.

Comment: Слишком абстрактный заголовок, сделал немного конкретнее. Вообще, неплохо бы и код функций прикладывать (у вас только одна). Плюс, код лучше не картинками давать, а именно кодом.